# Does the D-Wave 2000Q satisfy DiVincenzo's criteria?

Tags: experimental-realization, architecture, d-wave, adiabatic-model, scalability

[DiVincenzo's criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DiVincenzo%27s_criteria) for quantum computation are the following:

1. A scalable physical system with well characterized qubits.
2. The ability to initialize the state of the qubits to a simple fiducial
   state.
3. Long relevant decoherence times.
4. A “universal” set of quantum gates.
5. A qubit-specific measurement capability.

Are they satisfied by the D-Wave 2000Q?

---

This was originally part of [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/whats-a-qubit-on-d-wave-2000q) but is better suited to be a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

No, as point 4 is not satisfied.

The D-Wave machines are quantum annealers and thus not universal.

See [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/what-would-be-the-simplest-addition-that-would-make-the-d-wave-architecture-univ/) question on how to make from the D-Wave machine a universal quantum computer.